# CORBA ORB runtime define local IP interface usage

Tags: java, solaris, corba

We have an existing application which has set up a CORBA ORB runtime environment as client.

At the moment we don't specify any local interface (IP/Ethernet) to use and the runtime seems to get some default interface on our local machine. The machine used is Oracle with Solaris operating system.

The ORB runtime environment used here is Java 7 JDK built-in ORB.

Is there any way to explicitly indicate that a certain local IP interface should be used via some property to `ORB.init(...)`?

Comment: For what purpose? The default is to listen at all interfaces, i.e. 0.0.0.0 in IPv4-speak.

Comment: This is an ORB-specific setting, and something that each CORBA vendor specified differently. You should consult the Java 7 docs and look at the ORB properties that you could set for transport interface binding.

Answer (score 5):

For Oracle JDKs ORB it is

```
 -Dcom.sun.CORBA.ORBServerPort=10023 -Dcom.sun.CORBA.ORBServerHost=1.2.3.4
```

on cmdline or

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("com.sun.CORBA.ORBServerPort", "10000");
    prop.put("com.sun.CORBA.ORBServerHost", "11.1.1.11");
    ORB orb = ORB.init(args, prop);
```

if used programmatic.

Comment: If anyone is still doing CORBA and uses glassfish-corba-orb, the properties should have `com.sun.corba.ee` prefix instead of `com.sun.CORBA`.